# how to get items from menu in html

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio, razor

I've been trying to get menu item from  menu-id="2" to put some JavaScript in each item in it, but unfortunately it doesn't work.
I would appreciate some help.

```
<section id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center text-xs-center text-sm-left text-mdf left">            
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <h5>Information</h5>
        <vc:menu menu-id="2"></vc:menu>                    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Very unclear what you actually want to achieve or what problem you have with the code... Please [edit] post to clarify.

Comment: HI, please explain more about "vc" that you are using. You can try to use "id" instead of "item-id" so you can use getElementById()